# Angular universal installation on existing angular 2 app using cli

Tags: node.js, angular, angular-cli, angular-universal

I am facing a few issues while implementing the universal cli on existing angular 2 app by following the instruction from the link below
https://universal.angular.io/quickstart/

On the first command to install angular-universal

```
npm install body-parser angular2-universal preboot express --save
```

I am getting the errors below

```
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@^1.0.0 (node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.0.17: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\test-app\node_modules\node_modules\package.json'
npm WARN angular2-universal@2.1.0-rc.1 requires a peer of zone.js@~0.6.21 but none was installed.
npm WARN angular2-universal-polyfills@2.1.0-rc.1 requires a peer of zone.js@~0.6.21 but none was installed.
```

after executing the second command I am facing the errors listed below

```
/ Resolving "express" from "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/types/npm-express/40186271a77cdfad17681014be3ea8b05fc8dcf…- Resolving "mime" from "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/types/npm-mime/c7c5810698b7eaa421702a53644a8963d372f758/typi…\ Resolving "mime" from "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/types/npm-mime/c7c5810698b7eaa421702a53644a8963d372f758/typi…| Resolving "mime" from "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/types/npm-mime/c7c5810698b7eaa421702a53644a8963d372f758/typi…/ Resolving "mime" from "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/types/npm-mime/c7c5810698b7eaa421702a53644a8963d372f758/typi…- Resolving "mime" from "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/types/npm-mime/c7c5810698b7eaa421702a53644a8963d372f758/typi…\ Resolving "mime" from "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/types/npm-mime/c7c5810698b7eaa421702a53644a8963d372f758/typi…| Resolving "mime" from "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/types/npm-mime/c7c5810698b7eaa421702a53644a8963d372f758/typi…/ Resolving "mime" from "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/types/npm-mime/c7c5810698b7eaa421702a53644a8963d372f758/typi…- Resolving "mime" from "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/types/npm-mime/c7c5810698b7eaa421702a53644a8963d372f758/typi…\ Resolving "mime" from "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/types/npm-mime/c7c5810698b7eaa421702a53644a8963d372f758/typi…typings ERR! message Unable to find "node" ("npm") in the registry.
typings ERR! message However, we found "node" for 2 other sources: "dt" and "env"
typings ERR! message You can install these using the "source" option.
typings ERR! message We could use your help adding these typings to the registry: https://github.com/typings/registry
typings ERR! caused by https://api.typings.org/entries/npm/node/versions/latest responded with 404, expected it to equal 200
typings ERR!
typings ERR! cwd C:\test-app
typings ERR! system Windows_NT 10.0.14393
typings ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\Ajackus Consultancy\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\typings\\dist\\bin.js" "install" "node" "express" "body-parser" "serve-static" "express-serve-static-core" "mime" "--global"
typings ERR! node -v v4.6.0
typings ERR! typings -v 2.1.0
typings ERR!
typings ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
typings ERR!   <https://github.com/typings/typings/issues>
```

what am i missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nothing, those are warnings, not errors. You can most likely safely ignore those. It happens when a dependency is installed after the dependant.

the usage of `typings` is kinda deprecated in favour of `@types`. Instead of those command execute these, and remove your local typings folder:

```
npm install --save-dev @types/node 
npm install --save-dev @types/express 
npm install --save-dev @types/body-parser 
npm install --save-dev @types/serve-static 
npm install --save-dev @types/express-serve-static-core 
npm install --save-dev @types/mime
```

Comment: but how do i ensure whether angular2-universal has been installed?

Comment: check node_modules folder if there is a folder `angular2-universal`

Comment: yes it is there but now after executing the second command from tutorial i am getting the error listed below, perhaps you can help with that too.

Comment: I am still facing an issue when i try to run node server.js

Comment: import 'angular2-universal/polyfills';
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected reserved word
    at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:53:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:373:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:441:10)
    at startup (node.js:139:18)
    at node.js:974:3

Comment: @yaser guide from https://universal.angular.io/quickstart/ has a lot of gotchas and i think it's kinda outdated. I suggest to follow https://github.com/angular/universal-starter

Comment: @DDRamone Thanks!